# SDL Combining text and Geometry Rendering to one texture

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl2

Basically I'm trying to end up with a Texture class that can take in text and have it be drawn over simple geometry (such as a letter 'A' over a filled rectangle). However I'm running into issues when thinking about how to combine these two concepts.

First, following lazy foo's tutorials, [Geometry rendering](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/08_geometry_rendering/index.php) is simple and is done with an

```
SDL_RECT and SDL_RenderFillRect(SDL_Renderer*, &SDL_Rect);
```

However, when [rendering text](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/16_true_type_fonts/index.php) it uses Surfaces and Textures in order to 'draw' the text. Specifically these lines:

```
SDL_Surface* textSurface = TTF_RenderText_Solid( gFont, textureText.c_str(), textColor );
mTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface( SDL_Renderer*, textSurface );
```

My confusing comes from trying to figure out several things:

a) Is it possible to maybe first Render the Geometry to a texture, and then render the text over that same texture?

b) I believe a call to  [SDL_SetRenderTarget](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetRenderTarget) is going to be necessary, but I'm not sure where and when during my combination stage this would need to be done.

c) Right before posting this question, I saw further down on the tutorials [this link](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/43_render_to_texture/index.php) which describes rendering geometry to a texture, however I'm still not sure how to combine Text with this.

Any help is appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To anyone else that ever needs help, I found a simple solution after thinking about it real quick, just set the target and then Draw any geometry you need before rendering the texture.

```
void LTexture::render( int x, int y, SDL_Rect* clip, double angle, SDL_Point* center, SDL_RendererFlip flip )
{
//Set rendering space and render to screen
SDL_Rect renderQuad = { x, y, mWidth, mHeight };

//Set clip rendering dimensions
if( clip != NULL )
{
    renderQuad.w = clip->w;
    renderQuad.h = clip->h;
}
//Draw geometry
SDL_Rect fillRect = { 0, 0, mWidth, mHeight };
SDL_SetRenderDrawColor( gRenderer, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF );
SDL_RenderFillRect( gRenderer, &fillRect );

//Render to screen (when mTexture = a font loaded texture/surface)
SDL_RenderCopyEx( gRenderer, mTexture, clip, &renderQuad, angle, center, flip );
}
```